# I can't install js libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

```sh
PS D:\React> npm i -g expo-cli        
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'expo-cli@5.4.3',
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.      
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.      
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.      
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.8: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https:

changed 1528 packages, and audited 1529 packages in 4m
118 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

26 vulnerabilities (10 moderate, 16 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: It seems like you have an issue with the `package.json` file. Please may you share that?

Comment: you have older verison of node, update it.

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your Node.js version to v16.14.2 as it’s written in the `expo-cli`'s package.json file which can be seen [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/main/package.json).